# PHP + mysql not updating database

Tags: php, database

I was trying to make a edit user thing but the `$PDO` is not updating the database. I verified the variable that has  user edited values and it's correct, but it doesn't update the database at all.

```
require_once 'init.php';
session_start();
// resgata os valores do formulário
$usuario2 = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ?? null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ?? null;
$password2 = isset($_POST['password2']) ?? null; 
$acesso = isset($_POST['acesso']) ?? null;
$matricula = isset($_POST['matricula']) ??  null;


// validação (bem simples, mais uma vez)
if (empty($name) || empty($password)  || empty($matricula ||empty($usuario2) 
))
{
echo "Volte e preencha todos os campos";
exit;
}
if ($password != $password2){
echo "senhas não coincidem";

}
$passwordh = sha1(md5($password));




// atualiza o banco
$PDO = db_connect();
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name = :name, password = :password, acesso = 
:acesso, matricula = :matricula WHERE usuario = :usuario";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordh);
$stmt->bindParam(':acesso', $acesso);
$stmt->bindParam(':matricula', $matricula);
$stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario2,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($stmt->execute())
{
 echo "Dados atualizados";
 echo $usuario2;
 }
else
 {
 echo "Erro ao alterar";
 print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: does `$stmt->execute();` return true/false?? Also this `sha1(md5` is very bad. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: Debug debug debug. Turn on all error reporting, display mysql errors, show var_dumps of incoming and setup data... you may answer your own question :D

Comment: I second the switch to password_hash/password_verify. Its future self-mending, and grows with security needs.

Comment: alredy solved: removed the "isset"s in the code